# Why $A \rightarrow B \Leftrightarrow \textrm{( A is False or B is True )} $

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence

I am reading a book about Artificial intelligence and Knowledge representation and there is a logic formula that I cannot explain

Why $A \rightarrow B \Leftrightarrow \textrm{( A is False or B is True )} $ ?

Comment: You can simply express both statements using a truth table and note that they are equivalent. Alternatively, taking the negation of the right side, we obtain (A and (not B)) which indeed is the negation of A implies B.

Comment: Sorry, but could you be more explicit, I really a newbie with logic

Comment: The "explanation" is that that's the **definition** of the connective $\rightarrow$. It's a certain useful function of two logical variables.

Comment: @bof: historically who defined the connective $\to$?

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity maybe you should ask a question. There is already one on why material implication has the word "material" at the start of it, but I have never seen one asking about the origins of the connective itself.

Comment: Also @ArtificialStupidity, your about me section is a gem.

Comment: @user400188: Thank you. I posted a new question [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/12144/who-defined-a-to-b-neg-a-vee-b-and-why-was-it-defined-that-way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A \rightarrow B$ is False only when $A$ is True **AND** $B$ is False. So when is it True?

Comment: Waaa, ok it's really counter intuitive, thanks I will approve this answer

Comment: Just to help make it less counter intuitive, think that if you assume something true and make correct steps you should end up with something true. On the contrary, when you assume something wrong and make logical steps you could end with something right. Example, assume $2 = 1+1$ then $2 + 0 = 1+1+0$. True gives true. Now assume $2 = 1$ them $2 \times 0 = 1\times 0$. False gives true.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two ways

1. Check the truth table for the proposition

$$A \to B \leftrightarrow \neg A \vee B$$

And conclude it is a tautology, therefore $A \to B \iff \neg A \vee B$

2. Or think if they are truly equivalent (if they behave in the same way)

> Note that $A \to B$ is false only in the case that $A$ is true and $B$ is false. If $A$ is true, then $\neg A$ are false. So if $\neg A$ and $B$ are false, then $\neg A \vee B$ is false. And it is also the only way to get $\neg A \vee B$ false.
>
> For other combination of truth values for $A$ and $B$ you see that they are true in the same cases.
>
> Therefore they are equivalent because they behave in the same way.

Comment: Should that be "so if $\lnot A$ and $B$ *are* false, then $\lnot A\lor B$ is false"?

Comment: @user400188 you are right! I’m going to correct it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is called [*material implication*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_%28rule_of_inference%29). It is a boolean operator like **AND** or **OR**. The symbol isn't to be confused with 'metalogically implies' ($\implies$), which isn't an operator.

You can see the logic behind the definition if you read it as:

> If **A** doesn't have it (material possession), then it doesn't matter whether **B** does or not. If **A** does have it, then **B** must too.

Comment: I don’t know why you say that it’s not “implies”. The question is exactly about the logical connective “implies” and its truth table.

Comment: @ggeolier; good point, it is material **implication** after all! I still think it's a connector not an operator which confuses me about the symbol.

Answer (score 1):

- Suppose $A\to B$ holds.
- $A$ is either false or it is true.  If it is true, then $A\to B$ entails that $B$ is true too.
- So the supposition of $A\to B$ entails that $A$ is false or $B$ is true.

---

- Suppose $A$ is false or $B$ is true

  - In the case of $A$ being false, then $B$ can be derived under an assumption of $A$ by exploding the contradiction.
  - In the case of $B$ being true, then $B$ is still true under an assumption of $A$.
- Therefore, in either of its cases, the supposition entails $A\to B$

---

Therefore $A\to B$ is equivalent to $A\vee\neg B$ in classical logic.